# Unity click outside object, start dragging when on top

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm implementing an IDragHandler in Unity, where I want to not just be able to begin dragging the object when I touch it, but also if the pointer enters it from outside while down. The core of my code:

```
public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler, IPointerEnterHandler
{
    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        ...
    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        // TODO: Don't just check mouse, take touch into account!
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            this.OnBeginDrag(eventData);
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically, if the pointer is down when the pointer enters the object, I want to start dragging it. However, this code just seems to bug the EventSystem for that object, because when this code is executed nothing happens, and I suddenly can't even drag the object normally anymore.

Is there a way to manually trigger "OnBeginDrag" from a  C# script that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when I was creating a custom camera. The problem is your statement "if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))" doesnt return true if the mouse button was being held down before the event was triggered. Contrary to what I think is logical the "if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))" doesnt mean if mouse button is held down, it means something more like if mouse button is clicked while{stuff} then {more stuff}.

You should use "Input.GetButton()" instead of "Input.GetButtonDown()". Input.GetButtonDown() only returns true for the frame in which the button was pressed.

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/412117/do-something-while-key-is-pressed-and-held-down.html

Your question is a little unclear. Have you gotten the code to work at all in any respect, or is it just the dragging an object when the cursor enters from outside while mouse button is held down that you are wondering about?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
I interpreted "GetMouseButton" as "GetButton" but with specifically mouse buttons, as there is a "GetMouseButtonDown" function available, corresponding t "GetButtonDown", so if that's correct, then I should already have handled that issue.
Sorry for being unclear. My begin drag, drag and end drag works absolutely fine as they are. I just want to trigger the chain with a manual call to BeginDrag to start off my implemented Drag behaviour, even if the pointer down event occurred outside the object.

Comment: hmmm. I'm not sure then. I think your right about the get button thing being handled already. My mistake. what you should do now is use debug.log to see what is going wrong. for example you could put a debug.log inside of the if statement with something like debug.log("this part works"); to see if it is even firing. The message will show up in the console. That can help you to figure out what's not working and where to get started fixing it.

Comment: I know I've had all sorts of scripts not work for reasons I could never have figured out with out using debug.log. For example I once made a platform that was supposed to rotate in increments of 90 degrees, for example from 270 to 360, and so on. And it never fired and I couldnt figure out why the hell not. In the end it was because I was using an if statement, if degrees <360 degrees rotate +90 degrees, but the method I was using interpretted 360 degrees a being 0 degrees, so 270 is not less than 0 and the thing never fired until I changed it to 359.9. So debug.log is your friend.

Comment: Thank you! :) I found out that OnBeginDrag is actually called correctly, the problem is that I'm just calling OnBeginDrag, not kickstarting the drag event chain from UnityEngine.EventSystems. So, OnBeginDrag is called once but then OnDrag is not continously called by EventSystems.